# How to position element within a column to end (Vuetify)?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How to position both buttons below at the end of their respective columns ?

[image: buttons]

By default, the buttons are positioned to **start** in each column.

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-row justify="center"
       style="border: 1px solid;">
        <v-col 
          cols="12"
          sm="4"
          style="border: 1px solid red;"
        >
          <v-btn>Ok</v-btn>
        </v-col>
        <v-col 
          cols="12"
          sm="4"
          style="border: 1px solid blue;"
        >
          <v-btn>Cencel</v-btn>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

[Codepen.](https://codepen.io/begueradj-the-sasster/pen/RwNrbwm?&editable=true&editors=101)

Comment: Is your problem solved or still pending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: Add `class="text-right"` to both `<v-col>` elements if you want to position inline elements such as text.

Option 2: Add `class="d-flex justify-end"` to both `<v-col>` elements to position block elements.

Since the `<v-btn>` element is most likely displayed as an inline-block element, both options will work.

Comment: The second option works on both on Chrome and Firefox. The first one does not. Thank you for the feedback

Answer (score 3):

Just add `align="end"` to each of `v-col`.
Here is the [working codepen](https://codepen.io/loia5tqd001/pen/OJPMJBE?&editable=true&editors=101).

Because `v-col` is just `display: flex; flex-direction: column;`. Instead of `v-row` you use `justify` to align elements, in `v-col` you use `align`.

[image: snapshot]

Comment: thank you, but it does not work, the result of applying `align=end` is the same as what my screenshot shows

Comment: @Begueradj Have you tried my codepen above? Why am I seeing it different?

Comment: That is weird, I am not getting the same output as yours :(

Comment: I switched my browser to Chrome and found out your code works indeed. But on Firefox, it does not. So I give you +1